# Admin section showing CUSTOM Permalink structure thus resulting in permission error

Tags: wp-admin, dashboard

Used a plugin and it has pagination in backend but the pagination structure is taking custom permalink structure thus it is resulting in permission error when we click on paginations,

```
http://mydomain/wp-admin/admin.php?page=gift_registry/page/2/
```

The above URL resulting in error

```
http://mydomain/wp-admin/admin.php?page=gift_registry&paged=2
```

This is working fine.

How to make it default permalink structure so that I can access pages without any problems.

In brief how to give this plugin default permalink in admin section as we already have default permalink for page and post pagination in admin section.

Comment: Can you please tell the name of plugin which you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by doing as shown below.

I used Woo commerce Gift registry plugin replace the code with the below code in  `magenest-giftregistry-admin.php`

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
if (! defined ( 'ABSPATH' ))
    exit (); // Exit if accessed directly
class Magenest_Giftregistry_Admin {
        /**
         * Constructor.
         */
    public function __construct() {

    }
    public function giftregistry_manage() {
        if (isset ( $_REQUEST ['delete'] )) {
            if (isset ( $_REQUEST ['id'] ))
                $this->delete ( $_REQUEST ['id'] );
        } elseif (isset ( $_REQUEST ['edit'] )) {
            if (isset ( $_REQUEST ['id'] ))
                $this->edit ( $_REQUEST ['id'] );
        } elseif (isset ( $_REQUEST ['delete'] )) {
        } else {
            $this->index ();
        }
    }
    public function giftregistry_manages() {
        $rows_per_page = 10;
        $current = (intval(get_query_var('paged'))) ? intval(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;

        //$rows = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM subscriber ORDER BY sub_lname ASC');

        $rows = Magenest_Giftregistry_Model::get_all_giftregistry();
        $start = ($current - 1) * $rows_per_page;
        $end = $start + $rows_per_page;
        $end = (sizeof($rows) < $end) ? sizeof($rows) : $end;

        $pagination_args = array(
                'base' => esc_url_raw(@add_query_arg('paged','%#%')),
                'format' => '?page=%#%',
                'total' => ceil(sizeof($rows)/$rows_per_page) + 1,
                'current' => $current,
                'show_all' => False,
                'prev_next'    => True,
                'prev_text'    => __(' Previous'),
                'next_text'    => __('Next '),
                'type' => 'plain',
                'add_args'     => False
        );

        echo paginate_links($pagination_args);
    }

    public static function index() {
        // Test the use of paginate_links

        $rows_per_page = 5;

        $current = (isset($_REQUEST['paged'])&&intval($_REQUEST['paged']) ) ? intval($_REQUEST['paged']) : 1;

        // $rows is the array that we are going to paginate.
        $rows = Magenest_Giftregistry_Model::get_all_giftregistry();

        $max_page = ceil(sizeof($rows)/$rows_per_page);

        global $wp_rewrite,$wp_query;

        $pagination_args = array(
                'base' => esc_url_raw(@add_query_arg('paged','%#%')),
                'format' => '',
                'total' => ceil(sizeof($rows)/$rows_per_page),
                'current' => $current,
                'show_all' => false,
                'type' => 'plain',
        );

        //if( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
        //  $pagination_args['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg('s',get_pagenum_link(1) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged');

        if( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) )
            $pagination_args['add_args'] = array('s'=>get_query_var('s'));

        echo paginate_links($pagination_args);

        $start = ($current - 1) * $rows_per_page;
        $end = $start + $rows_per_page;
        $end = (sizeof($rows) < $end) ? sizeof($rows) : $end;

        echo '<table id="wishlit-tbl" class="wp-list-table widefat fixed">';
        ?>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
        <?php echo __('User id')?>
        </th>
        <th>
        <?php echo __('Registrant name')?>
        </th>
        <th>
        <?php echo __('Registrant email')?>
        </th>
        <th>
        <?php echo __('Date Time')?>
        </th>
        <th>
        <?php echo __('Delete')?>
        </th>
        <th>
        <?php echo __('Edit')?>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php 

        for ($i=$start;$i < $end ;++$i ) {
            $row = $rows[$i];
            $phpdate = strtotime( $row['event_date_time'] );
            $order_date = date('d M, Y h:i A', $phpdate);
            $http_schema = 'http://';
            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'])  {
                $http_schema = 'https://';
            }
            $delete_link = $http_schema. $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . '&delete=1';
            $edit_link = $http_schema. $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . '&edit=1';
            echo '<tr>';
            ?>
<td><?php echo $row['user_id']?> </td>
<td><?php echo $row['registrant_firstname']?> </td>
<td><?php echo $row['registrant_email']?> </td>
<td><?php echo $order_date ?> </td>
<td><a href="<?php echo $delete_link.'&id='.$row['id'] ?>"><?php echo __('Delete', GIFTREGISTRY_TEXT_DOMAIN)?></a>
</td>
<td><a href="<?php echo $edit_link.'&id='.$row['id'] ?>"><?php echo __('Edit', GIFTREGISTRY_TEXT_DOMAIN)?></a>
</td>
<td></td>


<?php 
            echo '</tr>';

        }
        echo '</table>';
    }

    public function delete($id) {

        Magenest_Giftregistry_Model::delete_giftregistry($id);
    }
    public function edit($id) {
        ?>
        <br>
        <button onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo get_admin_url(null,'admin.php?page=gift_registry')?>'" name="back" type="button" class="button button-primary button-large" id="back" accesskey="p" value="Back"><?php echo  __('Gift registry manage')?> </button>
        <?php 
        echo '<h2>Gift registry</h2>';
        ob_start();
        $template_path = GIFTREGISTRY_PATH.'template/account/';
        $default_path = GIFTREGISTRY_PATH.'template/account/';

        wc_get_template( 'add-giftregistry.php', array(
        'wid'       =>$id,

        ),$template_path,$default_path
        );
        echo  ob_get_clean();

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////GIFT REGISTRY ITEMS/////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $items = Magenest_Giftregistry_Model::get_items_in_giftregistry($id);
        ob_start();

        $template_path = GIFTREGISTRY_PATH.'template/account/';
        $default_path = GIFTREGISTRY_PATH.'template/account/';


        wc_get_template( 'my-giftregistry.php', array(
        'items'         =>$items,
        'wid'       =>$id
        ),$template_path,$default_path
        );
        echo  ob_get_clean();
    }

}
```